# Color Picker for specific Colors in touch UI AEM

Tags: aem

I am using the colorPicker for a widget:
[image]

Now i dont want to show the shades of the color and want to add custom colors.

```
freestylePaletteTypeboolean
```

**Displays the freestyle mode without palette shades.**

this property is not working  and the colors-name under colors node is also not working.

Please help.

Comment: OOTB color picker contains a lot of defects. You are doing nothing wrong, it's just color picker's render.jsp passes parameter object with name other than JS scripts expects. Now scripts themselves are very poorly implemented and contain number of other defects. So essentially you have option either to fix its bugs by yourself or go with custom implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://adobeaemclub.com/custom-color-picker-component-in-granite-ui-in-aem-6-1/)'s a starting point for implementing a color picker in AEM.

There's also a color palette picker example [here](http://experience-aem.blogspot.ro/2015/10/aem-61-touchui-rich-text-editor-color-picker-plugin.html) that could provide inspiration.

Comment: I want to add only specific colors.Color Picker shows a lot of colors.

Comment: @ShivaniGarg I added an example of color palette too.

Comment: Please include the most relevant points in the post itself. This is pretty much a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/188293). If these links happen to go dead at any point, the answer will lose its value.